# Obtaining charset of IMAP message body (PHP-IMAP extension)

Tags: php, utf-8, imap

Neither `imap_headerinfo` nor `imap_fetchstructure` include the blatantly apparent `Content-type` header in the results [obviously, I'd expect this to be found under `imap_headerinfo`]. What function can I utilize to get the raw headers so I can parse that header and convert the message body to UTF-8 accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course after I resort to asking a question I figure it out eight minutes later.
The solution is to run `imap_fetchmime` across the message/part combo like so

```
$headers = imap_fetchmime($this->imapStream, $msgNumber, $partNumber);
```

This will contain a `Content-type` header, if available, for each part.